# Excel Formula Bar Shows the Result NOT the Formula

Tags: excel, excel-2019

I have tried every possible solution to view a formula I wrote in Excel. It is completely hidden, all I see is the result, which makes *no sense* to me. Normally, the formula is displayed in the formula bar next to the fx symbol just below the ribbon, while the result of the formula is displayed within the cell. Not now.
I have clicked **Formulas > Formula Auditing > Show Formulas**. That doesn't work. I have gone to **file > options > advanced settings > display options for this workbook**. There I checked the option for '**show formulas in cell instead of calculated results**'. Nothing works. I've been using Excel for a decade, I never had an issue like this. Who wouldn't want to see the formulas they write-- this is driving me crazy??!!! This seems like such a simple issue and I've already wasted hours to no avail. Please help.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-formulas-f7f5ab4e-bf24-4efc-8fc9-0c1b77a5356f#ID0EDBBDBBD-button?

Comment: @GSerg none of those solutions work. Thanks though

Comment: Got a screenshot?

Comment: And are you certain there are formulas to begin with?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Is this while you are entering the formula, or some time after? The formula bar will show whatever is in the cell. If it is not showing the formula, then probably somehow the formula got replaced with it's result, either manually or by a macro.  What happens if you try this in a new workbook? If it occurs in a new workbook, does it occur if you open a new workbook in safe mode?

Comment: @ron_rosenfeld I used another workbook and it resolved the issue. I am not 100% certain but I believe that my worksheet was protected, though it didn't show that. I see that some others have had this issue so if anyone wants to try for a solution it may be helpful. My workbook contained only a few pages so it was easy for me to use another- this may not be the case with someone else. Cheers!